# Set position of a view

Tags: android, button, textview, android-dialogfragment

Here's simplified setup of mine:
I have a fragment, on which I have a button. What I want to do is to show an explanation to a user what that button does. I want this explanation to look like this: all views except that button become dimmed, there is a TextView near the button which says "Hey, this is a button!".

What I am doing:
1) I have created a DialogFragment, which duplicates that button and has a TextView near it. Layout looks like that:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/tutorial_fragment_element"
                android:layout_width="14dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:text="Button"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tutorial_fragment_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="The button!"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thus, `tutorial_fragment_element` is the element I should assign the same position as the original button.

Here's the code of the tutorial slide DialogFrament:

```
public class TutorialScreen extends DialogFragment {
    /**
     * View
     */
    @BindView(R.id.tutorial_fragment_element) LinearLayout mTutorialElement;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public TutorialScreen3() {

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_fragment, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateTargetPosition() {
        int x = getTargetX();
        int y = getTargetY();

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


        layoutParams.setMargins(x,y,0,0);

        mTutorialElement.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    }
}
```

In fact, it inherits from a custom DialogFragment of mine, in which I set up all essential stuff, as there are a lot of tutorial screens. It's not really important here but the actual way of how I get the position of the original button (not on the DialogFragment but on the Fragment itself):

```
protected void setDialogPosition() {
    if (mTargetView == null) {
        return; // Leave the dialog in default position
    }

    Rect rect = new Rect() ;
    mTargetView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

    int sourceX = rect.centerX()-(rect.width()/2)+mTargetView.getLeft()-2;
    int sourceY = rect.centerY()-(rect.height()/2+mTargetView.getBottom())-18;

    mTargetX = sourceX;
    mTargetY = sourceY;

    updateTargetPosition();
}
```

And here's the deal: the position of the button on the DialogFragment is always different than the position of the button of the original Fragment.

My question is this: how do you get the absolute position of the element and transfer that to the position of the element onto DialogFragment, shown ontop?

Comment: There a few libraries for this porpuse, here's one: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: @Kurlicue Hi! Unfortunately, this library does not suit my needs: some of the slides are really complex and rich of elements (ImageViews and etc)

Comment: It can be used for complex layouts. What doesn't suit you?

Comment: @skywall Well, for example, what if I need to have it rectangular, or have several active areas on the slide? Those libraries just generate a Bitmap and place it on top with a punched hole in it. That does not seem to be the solution for me